# Eigenvariety constructions: Links vs coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I'm trying to learn a bit about the construction of eigenverieties and I have the following questions. I have found 2 slightly different constructions of eigenvarieties, which I have a feeling must the basically the same thing but I'm slightly confused.

The first construction is due to Buzzard in his eigenvarieties paper, where he has a weight space $W$, a Hecke algebra $\pmb{T}$ and for every admissible affinoid open $X \subset W$ a Banach module $M_X$ with some compact operator on it. Moreover there is this notion of a link between $M_Y$ and $M_X$ for $Y \subset X \subset W$ both admissible affinoid opens. With this he then constructs the eigenvariety.

Now the other construction I found was due to Hansen where the data is: A weight space $W$, a Hecke algebra $\pmb{T}$, a spectral variety, and coherent sheaf $\mathscr{M}$ on the spectral varety and some map $\psi: \pmb{T} \to End(\mathscr{M})$. Now there is no mention of links here. He also says that in practice the cohenrent sheaf iss given by the "spreading out" of some module of automorphic forms.

So my questions are:
 1) Why does he not need to mention links? I'm guessing this is incorporated into the coherent sheaf in some way?

2) What exactly does "spreading out" mean in this setting?

Comment: The awful "link" business was because I had not yet understood the importance of working with locally analytic functions; I would work with $r$-analytic functions for some fixed radius $r$ and then I had to deal with the fact that sometimes $r$ would change. I would forget about it. If I'd worked a bit harder and set up a theory of compact operators on spaces of locally analytic functions then we wouldn't need these links. But aren't the links to define the spectral variety, which Hansen has already?

Comment: Oh ok, I must of misunderstood the links then. So they are part of Hansen's spectral variety. So I guess this coherent sheaf buisness is a fancy way of packaging the system of Banach modules used? Although I'm still not 100%  sure what spreading out means..

Comment: I guess that the fibre of the coherent sheaf at some point on the spectral variety (a point gives a weight and some eigenvalue for some compact Hecke operator or perhaps some system of compact Hecke operators, there are probably several ways of setting things up) will be some space of "p-adic automorphic forms" of that weight which form the generalised eigenspace for that eigenvalue. "Spread out" just probably means that for lots of points this space will equal the space of classical automorphic forms of that weight and that eigenvalue (by a control theorem).